# Repetitive service design Android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have following design in my app: I have a one activity that sets repeating alarm that launches receiver that starts my service. Every minute. In my service, I set Start Sticky but once Android decides to kill my service, I can't get it to restart. It's Android 4.4.2. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, i1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 60 * 1000, pi);
}
```

here is the receiver

```
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Starting Service");
    Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, MyLocationService.class);
    arg0.startService(intent);
}
```

and service:

```
private static PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
private static OkHttpClient client;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, Constants.TAG);
    wl.acquire();
    client = new OkHttpClient();
    new GetLocation(MyLocationService.this).execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely seeing an interaction with power management and alarms.  Starting with API 19 all alarms are *inexact* by default, so they will be collated with other alarms.  Further, once the device has entered into a lower power state, alarms are delivered to `BroadcastReceiver`s and the device guaranteed to stay awake as long as the receiver is executing its `onReceive()` method.  Once it returns from that method (and any other `BroadcastReceiver` associated with the alarm runs), the device will immediately go to a low power state again.  Since your app had previously been killed, the `Service` is no longer running and will not get CPU time.

The way to resolve this is to use a `WakefulReceiver` which takes a wakelock when it runs `onReceive()`, starts your `Service` for processing.  The `Service` will then release the wakelock when it is done processing.  This article will give you a good explanation of this: http://po.st/7UpipA

Note that waking up every minute is going to seriously degrade the battery life of the device, so you should consider backing this off.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I think I solved it using AlarmManager.setExact() therefore, I set alarm each time my service is launched in OnStartCommand

Comment: You will still ultimately run into issues with power management if you are not managing your wakelocks as described.

Comment: Is there any difference between acquiring wakelock in service itself and the BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: No, taking a wakelock will prevent the system from going to sleep...until you get to Android M and beyond.  At that point the system Doze mode will ignore wakelocks completely.  However, the reason you need to take the wakelock in the `BroadcastReceiver` is explained above and in the article.